# Splitting JS libraries with laravel mix

Tags: jquery, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm currently trying to split `JQuery` from its plugins using `laravel mix`. Ideally, I want my views to load only what they need but I can't figure out how to do that the right way with `npm`.

For example, I'm using the `datatables.net` and `jquery-mask-plugin` packages. Both of them depend on `JQuery` to work.

### Currently, what I have is the following

`resources/js/app.js`

```js
// Core
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');
// Plugins
require('datatables.net');
require('jquery-mask-plugin');
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');
```

```xml
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#sometable').dataTable(); // Works as expected
});
</script>
```

This generates a single `public/js/app.js` file. I want it to generate 3 files (1 for the 'core' and 2 for the plugins).

### What I've tried

Making separate files for each of the plugins but I run into an issue when I do it like this.

`resources/js/datatables.js`

```js
require('datatables.net');
```

`resources/js/jquery.mask.js`

```js
require('jquery-mask-plugin');
```

`webpack.mix.js`

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')          // public/js/app.js
   .js('resources/js/datatables.js', 'public/js')   // public/js/datatables.js
   .js('resources/js/jquery.mask.js', 'public/js'); // public/js/jquery.mask.js
```

I'm including `app.js` in all my views. If I try to include one of the plugins, they do not work.

```xml
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/datatables.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#sometable').dataTable(); // $(...).dataTable() is not a function
});
</script>
```

### My current workaround

Copying the scripts from `node_modules` instead of compiling them using `mix`'s `script`.

`webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js') // public/js/app.js
   .scripts(
       ['node_modules/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask.js'],
       'public/js/jquery.mask.js'
   );                                      // public/js/jquery.mask.js
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: nope, kept using my workaround